# why is my userform value not updating cell in lookup worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to do a vlookup in a table, which houses budget $ for our departments at work. I need to separately send this $ figure to the table to update their budget numbers.

I was assuming I could just do a lookup and then replace that value like:

`application.vlookup(me.txtELT.value, thisworkbook.worksheets("Summary Tab")`
`.range("A:I"),9,false).value = me.txtELTUnreqddollars.value`

but this isn't working. I don't want to get into a looping structure just to update one thing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vlookup` returns a value, not a cell. You maybe want to use Find() or Match() if you need a cell reference to work with.

Eg:

```vb
Dim m

With thisworkbook.worksheets("Summary Tab").range("A:I")
    m = Application.Match(me.txtELT.value,.Columns(1),0)
    If not iserror(m) then
        .cells(m,9).value = me.txtELTUnreqddollars.value
    End If
end with
```